# iconCls is not working tab panel bar position is top

Tags: sencha-touch-2, tabbar, tabpanel

Why iconCls is not working in tab panel bar when tab bar position is top in sencha touch 2?

It work fine when tab bar position is bottom.
Why it is not working when tab bar position is top?

```
    Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'top',

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        }
    ]
});
```

output of above code:

[image]

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        }
    ]
});
```

output of above code:

[image]

Why it is not working in top position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the way that is defined in Sencha Touch framework classes.

If you want it your way, just override them :)

Answer (score 0):

they designed it that way..

in their opinion if the tab panel is on the bottom of the screen it can look good with icon but if its on the top of the screen it doesn't go well with icon..

that being said I'm kind of agree with that decision but if you insist otherwise maybe you can try adding button as item of the tab panel and put the icon inside the button